How to provide "Login with Telegram" functionality on a React Native app?
I am using the Telegram widget on my web app, but I'm now building a React Native app and I would need a way to let my users authenticate with Telegram.
Ideally I'd like to use a standard OAuth2 flow but I can't find any details on the required parameters, such as authorizationEndpoint, tokenEndpoint and revocationEndpoint required to use libs like expo-auth-session.
What are my options?

to integrate telegram login functionality into a react native app, you can use telegram official Widget for logging in with Telegram along with web based authentication

the official widget is web-based, it needs a browser to work

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
